# Http request for auth in Dropbox using Qt5

Tags: qt, api, http, https, dropbox

I have tryed to realize acces to files on Dropbox using Qt. I have create app on off. site, dir was created. But I couldn't auth there with app.
I have create those test request for this.

```
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/link/"));
request.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + QString("keyApp:AppSecret").toLatin1().toBase64());
replyer = manager->post(request, "link=https://www.dropbox.com/sh/<DIR URL>?dl=0");
```

On "link=" what I need to put? Where I can find those link? I can get this link only by creating link from site with adding sharelink, I don't think that it works like that. But even with this link I still get errors with

> \"access_denied:unsupported_app_type\"}".

Also I have tryed to make those request

```
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/auth/token/from_oauth1"));
request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Bearer тут accesTokenFromSite");
replyer = manager->post(request, "{\"oauth1_token\": \"whereFindThoseParam?\",\"oauth1_token_secret\": \""}");
```

Where could I find last two parametrs? With request with default values I get error

> "Error in call to API function \"auth/token/from_oauth1\": Invalid
>   HTTP header \"Authorization\": expecting \"Basic\" auth"

Also I have tried to do with

```
QUrl url("https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/token");
url.setUserName("KEY");
url.setPassword("SECRET");
QNetworkRequest request(url);
request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
QHttpMultiPart *mpart = new QHttpMultiPart(this);
QHttpPart part1;
part1.setBody("grant_type=authorization_code");
mpart->append(part1);
QHttpPart part2;
part2.setBody("code=CODE");
mpart->append(part2);
replyer = manager->post(request, mpart);
```

But still getting errors :

> "{\"error_description\": \"No auth function available for given
>   request\", \"error\": \"invalid_request\"}"

Comment: Not an answer but maybe look at https://github.com/osoftteam/dropboxQt if it can already do what you need?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make a variety of different API calls that do different things. What's your actual goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to *create a new app on the Dropbox Platform* to get credentials (app key and app secret) to be used in the app you develop. You can do it on the following page: [Create a new app on the Dropbox Platform](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/create).

You should read through the [Dropbox for HTTP Developers](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation). There you can select your app (the one you created on Dropbox) in the dropdown and populate access token and you get ready-made examples to test with [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/).

Once you have enough understanding of the http API you can start implementing in Qt. It might be a good idea to inspect [QtDropbox](https://github.com/lycis/QtDropbox) project sources (and even build and run its test client). Note that QtDropbox currently supports only [API v1](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1). You can find API v1 -> v2 migration guide from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/migration-guide).

**UPDATE**

To get forward, see below steps to generate an access token to be able to make API calls **for your own account without going through the authorization flow**. To obtain access tokens for other users, you will have to implement the standard OAuth flow which is described in the documentation even not very clearly.

Go to your app on [apps page](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps)

- Set `Permission type` to *Full Dropbox* to be able to do all kinds of
  operations
- Click *Generate* under `Generated access token`
- Copy your
  token: e.g. 2on**_M7cJ***Qe3gmtQJK

Let's assume there is a folder named *misc* in the root of the Dropbox account's folder structure.

List folder contents using curl:

```
curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer 2on**_M7cJ***Qe3gmtQJK' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"path":"/misc"}'
```

You should get back a json object with folder contents.

As the documentation says: The [Dropbox API explorer](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/) is the easiest way to get started making API calls.

To get forward on how to get access for your app to somebody else's Dropbox account (if that's your goal) open following page to a browser from your app:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<your app key>&response_type=code
```

You will get a token which can then be used in call to `https://api.dropboxapi.com/oauth2/token` together with app key and secret.

Hope this helps you to get forward.

Comment: Read documentation? Thx, captain. I already read it, And tryed using simple curl, without Qt, and project was created, and I used all datas that I have see there. But still getting errors, at Qt and at curl (the same).

Comment: The core of my answer was in the first paragraph. Did you do it, and and then went back to documentation and populated tokens and then tried with correct tokens and not with default values?

Comment: I already got key app and secret, just don't put here in requests, as like my passwords, logins and other keys